# Player fold in split pot, is he part of main pot?

Tags: texas-hold-em, all-in, fold-equity

Player A is all in to which player B and C matches the amount, then we created a split pot for player B and C and now Player B puts some amount to which Player C folds. Would player C win anything from the pot created between A,B,C.

Round 1: 
Player A: 50 (all in)
Player B: 50
Player C: 50

Round 2:
Player B: 200
Player C: Fold

Is player C part of round 1 pot?

Answer (score 3):

No, once C folds, he is out of the hand, and has no claim to any main or side pots.